# python - s3 Boto3 read N number of lines per iteration from large file

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to process all records of a large file from s3 using python in batch of N no of line. i have to fetch N no of line per iteration. each line has some json object.

Here are some things I've already tried:

**1)**
I tried the solution mentioned here
[Streaming in / chunking csv's from S3 to Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51085539/streaming-in-chunking-csvs-from-s3-to-python)
but it breaks my json structure while reading bytes of data.

**2)**

```
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=fname)
data=obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()
```

It take more time to read large file with 100k lines. it will return list of lines which we can further iterate to get number of line from data variable.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [smart_open](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open) does the trick.

```
pip install smart_open[s3]
```

After installing it...

```
from smart_open import open

client = boto3.client("s3")
transport_params = {'client': client}
with open('s3://%s/%s' % (bucket_name, fname), 'wb', transport_params=transport_params, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(json.loads(line))
```

You could use [iter_lines](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html) too:

```
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=fname)
for line in obj['Body'].iter_lines(chunk_size=1024, keepends=False):
    print(json.loads(line))
```

Comment: Hi.. this will give me a single line and chunk size is in bytes. show it wont return me N no of lines as required.

Answer (score 0):

Those who are looking for similar solution. i have utilized pandas library to get N no of Lines in loop.

Below is my code implementation it will give 50 lines per iteration

```
for records in pd.read_json(obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'), lines=True, chunksize=50):
    print(records)
```